# Translation/l10n/i18n static pages and single-page apps

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, translation

What are current best-practices and libraries for translating statically served web-pages and single-page apps?

We would prefer to do it on the client-side, and would be awesome to automatically detect user's locale and allow them to change language.

If that matters, we use Marionette.js, underscore.js templates, and bootstrap for layout.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few libraries out there including Mozilla's [l20n.js](http://l20n.org) and [webl10n](https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/webL10n) by  Fabien Cazenave.

Please check [this article](http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/localizing-single-page-applications/) for more help on the 2nd one that explains with examples for SPA.